# Can we use cisco MDS 9700 without Fabric Module

Tags: cisco, san

We have Cisco MDS 9710 and we want turn it on with 1 I/O module. Is it mandatory to install Fabric Module for it?

My question is , Does MDS 9700 works without Fabric Module or no?

Thanks,

Comment: That seems to depend on the I/O module in question. I'd check the [product datasheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/storage-networking/mds-9700-series-multilayer-directors/data_sheet_c78-727769.html) first.

Comment: Could you please show me where it explain in datasheet?